# translateX = event.offsetX setter on mousemove event return 1 - sometimes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, events, mouseevent

Quick and simple question, about a some sort of scrubber thing. See the fiddle below.

When binding to the mousemove event (using jQuery), and setting the transformX property when moving in the positive direction, there is about a 1/2 change it returns 1.

`$floater.css('transform', 'translateX('+event.offsetX+'px)');`

Same setup with left offset - No issues!

Browser inconsistencies:

- Firefox does nothing
- IE does the same as Chrome
- Heads up, IE decided to crash on opening my fiddle

Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/n3Z3Y/3/

Comment: use $floater.css('transform', 'translateX('+event.pageX+'px)'); it works.. fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/krunalp1993/n3Z3Y/6/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, that fixes the firefox issue atleast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because when mouse cursor is over your 'floater' div you lose mouseover on the container parent. A quick fix could be to return false when mouse is over your floater div. Fiddle updated [here](http://jsfiddle.net/n3Z3Y/8/).

```
$floater.on('mousemove', function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.preventDefault();

    // cross browser propagation stopping...
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Thanks! Pretty obvious, but was looking for two hours in the wrong direction.